# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, json, android-studio

I'm trying to insert a user into my database given a username, email and password.
MyRequest class is suppose to contain the connection and the registration of a user.

In my opinion the problem occurs in the register methode of MyRequest class where i'm trying to get all the error messages with `JSONObject messages = json.getJSONObject("message");`

**MyRequest.java**

```
package com.chamikathalagalage.loginregister.myrequest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by 85RM5Z on {10/02/2021}.
 */
public class MyRequest {

    private Context context;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    public MyRequest(Context context, RequestQueue queue) {
        this.context = context;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void register(final String pseudo, final String email, final String password, final String password2, RegisterCallback callback){

        String url = "http://192.168.56.1/mangaReader/register.php";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Declaration d'un hashMap qui va contienir notre clé et la message d'erreur.
                Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                    //Vérifie si la clé error est à true ou false.
                    Boolean error = json.getBoolean("error");

                    if (!error){
                        //l'inscription s'est bien déroulée
                        callback.onSuccess("Vous êtes bien inscrit");
                    }else{
                        //On recupere chaque message d'erreur
                        JSONObject messages = json.getJSONObject("message");

                        if (messages.has("pseudo")) {
                            errors.put("pseudo", messages.getString("pseudo"));
                        }
                        if (messages.has("email")) {
                            errors.put("email", messages.getString("email"));
                        }
                        if (messages.has("password")) {
                            errors.put("password", messages.getString("password"));
                        }

                        callback.inputErrors(errors);
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("APP", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof NetworkError){
                    callback.onError("Impossible de se connecter");
                }else if(error instanceof VolleyError){
                    callback.onError("Une error s'est produite");
                }
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("pseudo", pseudo);
                map.put("email", email);
                map.put("password", password);
                map.put("password2", password2);

                return map;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);

    }

    public interface RegisterCallback{
        void onSuccess(String message);
        void inputErrors(Map<String, String> errors);
        void onError(String message);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
W/System.err:     at com.chamikathalagalage.loginregister.myrequest.MyRequest$1.onResponse(MyRequest.java:43)
W/System.err:     at com.chamikathalagalage.loginregister.myrequest.MyRequest$1.onResponse(MyRequest.java:36)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**PHP file**

```
<?php

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=manga_app","root","");

$results['error'] = false;
$results['message'] = [];


if(isset($_POST)){

    if(!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password2'])){

        $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

        // vérification du pseudo

        if(strlen($pseudo) < 2 || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+$/", $pseudo) || strlen($pseudo) > 60){
            $results['error'] = true;
            $results['message']['pseudo'] = "Pseudo invalide";
        }else{

            // Vérifier que le pseudo n'existe pas

            $requete = $db->prepare("SELECT id_user  FROM utilisateur WHERE pseudo = :pseudo");
            $requete->execute([':pseudo' => $pseudo]);
            $row = $requete->fetch();
            if($row) {
                $results['error'] = true;
                $results['message']['pseudo'] = "Le pseudo est déjà pris";
            }
        }

        // Vérification de l'email

        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $results['error'] = true;
            $results['message']['email'] = "Email invalide";

        }else{
            // Vérifier que l'email n'est pas utilisé

            $requete = $db->prepare("SELECT id_user FROM utilisateur WHERE email = :email");
            $requete->execute([':email' => $email]);
            $row = $requete->fetch();
            if ($row) {
                $results['error'] = true;
                $results['message']['email'] = "L'email existe déjà";
            }
        }

        // Verification du password

        if($password !== $password2){
            $results['error'] = true;
            $results['message']['password'] = "Les mots de passe doivent être identiques";
        }

        if($results['error'] == false) {
            
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            // Insertion
            
            $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO utilisateur(pseudo, email, password) VALUES(:pseudo, :email, :password)");

            $sql->execute([":pseudo" => $pseudo, ":email" => $email, ":password" => $password]);

            if(!sql){
                $results['error'] = true;
                $results['message'] = "Erreur lors de inscription";
            }
            
        }

    }else{
        $results['error'] = true;
        $results['message'] = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs";
    }

    echo json_encode($results);
}

?>
```

Please Help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exception seems to be coming from `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);`, not only because of the ex. msg but because of the stack trace: `MyRequest.java:43`.

Comment: @naicolas yes i agree with you, here i'm trying to transform the String response into a JSONObject